# What does this matrix notation mean $(A)^\bot$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

I was doing a multiple choice exercise where I had to determine which one of the options was a basis for the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 & 0 & -1\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 0\\
5 & 4 & 3 & -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

By testing all of the options (which I won't list here), I was able to find the correct one. However, one of the options was the following

$$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
1 \\
5 \\
\end{pmatrix}\, ,\,
\begin{pmatrix}
4 \\
1 \\
5 \\
\end{pmatrix}\right\} \;\text{is a basis of } (\text{Col } A)^\bot$$

and I had never seen the perpendicular sign $\bot$ used in matrix notation before. I tried doing a little research to no avail. My theory is that it's some alternate form of the transpose symbol, or maybe even the adjacency matrix normally denoted by $\dagger$ (I think). None of my classmates or any upperclassmen knew what it was for.

Comment: It means the orthogonal complement; $(\text{Col}\,A)^{\perp}$ is the set of all vectors orthogonal to the column space of $A$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Is that done with Gram-Schmidt by chance...?

Comment: @symplectomorphic Oh ok, that makes a lot more sense, thanks!

Comment: Is what done? You mean how do you describe the space $(\text{Col}\,A)^{\perp}$? Well, suppose $v$ is in this set. Then you need $a_i\cdot v=a_i^Tv=0$ for all the columns $a_i$ of $A$. All these statements together imply $A^Tv=0$, where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$. So $v$ must be in the kernel of the transpose. The converse is true as well. So to describe $(\text{Col}\,A)^{\perp}$, look for a basis of the kernel of $A^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for a set $S$ in a Hilbert space, we have
$S^\bot = \{ x | \langle x,s \rangle = 0, \text{ for all } s \in S \}$.

Comment: I found the same explanation in my notes. What's strange is that this exercise was given to us 3 weeks earlier...oh well, thanks anyways!